# c++ Error zaman1.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++

I have been struggling for this I cant find a solution

```
#ifndef ZAMAN1_H
#define ZAMAN1_H

class Zaman{   
    public:    
        Zaman();    
        void zamanAyarla(int,int,int);    
        void askeriYaz();    
        void standartYaz();    
    private:    
        int saat;    
        int dakika;    
        int saniye;    
};

#endif

#include< iostream>

using std::cout;

#include"zaman1.h"

Zaman::Zaman(){saat=dakika=saniye=0;}

void Zaman::zamanAyarla(int h,int m,int s){

    saat=(h>=0&&h<24)?h:0;
    dakika=(m>=0&&m<60)?m:0;
    saniye=(s>=0&&s<60)?s:0;

}
```

.....
  .....
  .....
when I compailed this I got

> "Error zaman1.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated."

I also tried include"ZAMAN1_H",< zaman1_h>,< ZAMAN1_H> same result ...

Comment: Your spacing at the includes is weired. Try `#include <iostream>` and `include "zaman1.h"`.

Comment: Do you have the listing in two files? The first part (from `ifndef` to `endif`) should be in a file called `zaman1.h` and then the rest (from `include <iostream>` on) should be in another file (`zaman1.cpp` for example). They have to be in the same directory.

Comment: yes I did it and solved thx.

Comment: @MKS you did what? to which comment are you referring?

Comment: @tobi303 You know the one.

Comment: I put the part after endif in another file zaman1.cpp